# Importing multiple gradle dependencies which depend on each other

Tags: android, gradle

Supposing I have a project with dependencies on modules `A` and `B`. If module `B` internally is also dependent on module `A`, do I need to add them both to the original project or just adding dependency on module B would also allow access to module A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, adding **only the `B` module dependency will be sufficient**. Using either `api` or `implementation` (or even the deprecated `compile`). You will be able to access code of `A` module through it even without explicitly specifing its dependency in your `build.gradle` file. Also, I would suggest you read this artice [Implementation Vs Api in Android Gradle](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa), as it goes more deep into the issue as well as explaining the differences between the `api` and `implementation`, which I mentioned earlier.

Comment: The only situation where one may want to declare A is to force the usage of a specific version of A and then excluding the one that is in B, right?

Comment: @AkshayChoudhry, yes, this might be the case, though in this case you may also want to exclude the unwanted version of A (such are called transitive dependencies) from the B dependency declaration. For example if B depends on a newer version of A, and you need a specific one, as they might cause conflict etc.

Comment: This answers it. Thanks. Follow up though. If B uses version 1.0 of A and I add 1.1 of A into my project, will it only use the latest version for building the apk and then B would also reference that version of A? Edit: I think you answered this with the comment

Answer (score 1):

you just need importing dependencies B